# Getting TypeError: d.collection is undefined error while creating collection in Backbone.js

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express

I'm new to Backbone.js.I have tried to create collection in Backbone while creating that i'm getting error as ' d.collection is undefined error'.

```
    $(function(){
       var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
       var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                          url: '/index.html',
                          model: MyModel
                         });
      var coll = new MyCollection();
      coll.fetch({
          error: function (collection, response) {
             console.log('error', response);
          },
         success: function (collection, response) {
            console.log('success', response);
         }
   });


    });
```

Also i need to handle the express route method result in Backbone.How can i handle that..

app.js

```
  app.all('*',function(req,res){
      var result={a:'a',b:'b',c:'c'};
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/json'});
      res.write(JSON.stringify(result));
      res.end();
  });
```

Comment: are you sure that its `url: '/index.html',` ? shouldn't that be `url: '/index.json',`

Comment: @rajkamal yes my url is /index.html

Answer (score 3):

I had this error, and found that it goes away when you remove backbone.localStorage-min.js from your head includes.

Comment: You saved 10 years of my life. I was struggelig with this error for 2 days. Really appreciate it.